# Please specify your BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID and BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32, blynk

in this case i want to make a dust monitoring projet with Blynk connection. But when i integrated my program code with blynk template code, i meet some error :
**#error "Please specify your BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID and BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME"**

In this case im very confused, I had declared BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID and BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME at the beginning of the program like the following snippet of my program code:

```
#include <Blynk.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp32.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID "xxxxxxx"
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME "xxxxxxx"
#define BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN "xxxxxxxx"
```

But the error says, i must to defined the BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID and BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME.
How supposed i do in this case? Thank you

In this case i already try to downgrade my Blynk library from 1.3.0 to 1.2.0, and the problem BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID and BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME error was solved.
But with Blynk 1.2.0 libraries my ESP-32 cannot connect to Blynk Cloud.

If i upgrade my Blynk Library to 1.3.0 again, the problem comes again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr: Put your `#define` BEFORE any Blynk headers

`#include` will essentially "copy-paste" the file you're including at the place you have the include. So if the Blynk library has this in one of the headers:

```
#ifndef BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID
#error "Please specify id"
#endif
```

and you define the `BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID` later, it will not compile, because at the compilation, the full code will look like this:

```
// from Blynk.h
#ifndef BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID
#error "Please specify id"
#endif
// Blynk.h end
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID "xxxxxxx"
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME "xxxxxxx"
#define BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN "xxxxxxxx"
```

Since the check is before the `#define`, it will not compile. Also, since this is an auth token, **you probably should not define it in code**. Instead, you can pass parameter to the compiler to set `#define` that will apply for the entire compilation.

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot. It Works hahaha....
From your suggestion, i put a #define blynk before #include blynk, and it works. Thank you man for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I have change in Code the name of "#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME "xxxxxxx"", in BLYNK Version 1.2 no problem. In version 1.3 you receive an error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Put the #include of the Blynk Library, AFTER #defines of your 3 Blynk variables, BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME and BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN.
e.g

```
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID           "TMPL?????-u"
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME         "ESP32DHT11"
#define BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN            "LmnKOfjfkesoknjjjdtrash"

THEN!!    #include <BlynkSimpleEsp32.h>
```

good luck -
Keith